# Построить Машину Тьюринга на проверку правильности скобок

Tags: виртуальная-машина

Помогите, пожалуста. Задача: записать систему правил для МТ.
Дан алфавит A = {(, ), _} и внутренние состояния Q = {q1, q2, …, qz}.
Нужно проверить верно ли в исходной
последовательности расставлены скобки.

Алгоритм на простом языке: (но не факт, что без ошибок)
Есть лента, скобочная последовательность ограничена символами _.
Головка находится в самом левом положении. Работа машины: сначала ГЗЧ движется вправо до первой правой скобки, заменяет ее символом X, переходит в состояние q1 и движется влево до ближайшей левой скобки,
заменяет ее символом X, переходит в состояние q0 , и челночное движение повторяется. Если машина, находясь в состоянии q1, достигает левого символа _, то печатает "0" и останавливается – скобочное выражение неправильно.  Если машина, находясь в состоянии q0, достигает правого символа _, не обнаружив больше правой скобки, то переходит в заключительное состояние q2, связанное с движением влево, и в последний раз просматривает последовательность: не осталась ли непарная левая скобка. Если по пути встретится левая скобка, то машина печатает "0" и останавливается. При достижении в состоянии q2 левого символа _, машина печатает "1" и останавливается – скобочное выражение правильно.

То есть (()()) - правильное выражение, а )()( или (() - неправильные
Примерно, как я понимаю:

```
q0 (  -->  q0 ( R
q0 ) --> q1 X L
q0 (  --> q1 X R
q1 _  --> qz 0 
q0 _  --> qz 1
```

Comment: Добавьте в вопрос вашу попытку написать таблицу правил. Форумчане помогут исправить ошибки.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.